# Google Maps Api error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null at
>   Object._.Og (js?key=AIzaSyANNd20FnR5uWOum1z4Oftu1Ip2Fj4yV-A:88) at new
>   Sg (js?key=AIzaSyANNd20FnR5uWOum1z4Oftu1Ip2Fj4yV-A:89) at exito
>   (ejercicio1.js:15)

Este es mi codigo, el error le da en la linea de la variable map. El script de js y el de la api de google maps con la clave están puestos perfectamente, no sé de dónde puede venir el fallo:

```
function cargaPagina(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(exito, error);

    document.getElementById("ubicacion-actual").innerHTML="Ubicación actual";
}

function exito(location){

    var uluru = {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });

}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código html  para ver mejor el  contexto en el cual se produce el error.

Comment: El fallo, me da ahí, en el html simplemente tengo un div con id="mapa". Que es donde quiero mostrar el mapa @bercklynCarlosviza

Comment: Te extá diciendo que no encuentra el elemento con id `mapa`. Puede que estés ejecutando la función antes de que el DOM haya terminado de renderear, pero parece improbable. Tendrías que mostrar el html completo